# Different time zones for Azure web app

Tags: azure, web-applications, timezone

We have a web app running in North UK for which we have explicitly specified a time zone using `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` in App Settings. It's a multi tenant SaaS application with Shared Database  architecture. Now we have a new client from US, who is going to use the app. but being in a different timezone it is changing dates and times that are stored in the database.

What should be the best practice to get the app working correctly for different time zones? Should I deploy a separate website for each time zone or should I handle it in code?

Comment: Always store Dates in [Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). When displaying information, you can format it based on the user location.

Comment: While this question is a bit broad and opinionated for Stack Overflow, as there is no "specific" right answer to this, and there could legitimately be reasons to store local-time content: Storing multiple time zones is just adding to things you need to deal with, vs storing everything as UTC and viewing locally in the time zone of choice. I'd follow @rickvdbosch's advice, and save yourself a ton of headache.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. So basically, in my case, as I already have the web server to set up to use GMT time zone, I need to first convert from GMT to UTC and then convert it back to user's location. The reason is, at this point I can't change website's time zone as it will affect all existing data. I then need to figure out how to get user's location and change web.config dynamically?

Comment: @rickvdbosch - generally yes, but there are edge cases, such as scheduling of future events, where the event-local time zone is preferable.  Also, whole dates (such as birthdays) are generally stored timeless, and thus a time zone is applied upon interpretation rather than at time of storage.  Just pointing out to be careful with the "always UTC" advice - there is context to consider. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things:

- The best practice for server-side code, regardless of language or platform, is for it to be time-zone independent.  That means *not* making any hard-coded dependencies on a single time zone, whether that comes from a config file, hosting setting, or server setting.

  - For .NET code, that means you should never use `DateTime.Now`, `DateTimeKind.Local`, `TimeZoneInfo.Local`, and related APIs, because they take their time zone from the server setting.
- Instead, use APIs that work with UTC, and/or with specific time zones or time zone offsets.

  - For .NET code, that means using things like `DateTime.UtcNow`, `DateTimeOffset`, `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`, `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById`, and several others.  Alternatively, consider using [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org), which offers a more comprehensive and consistent API.
- Generally, an application should track the time zone of a user and/or location as a separate field, stored as a string time zone identifier, either in Windows time format, or IANA time zone format.  Read [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for more details (the section titled "Time Zone Databases").
- Regarding the `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` setting:  Only use when *all* of the following are true:

  - You are hosting an application that uses the system-local time zone.  For example, it may get the current time by calling `DateTime.Now`.
  - All of the users of the application are always in the same time zone.
  - For whatever reason, you cannot make changes to the application to make it time-zone independent.

My personal opinion is that the `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` setting should not exist.  There is no need for it in a properly designed application.  It is a crutch that should be using sparingly and as a last resort only.

Comment: Thanks for all the information @Matt, it's very helpful. However it seems all this should be considered before developing the app, what is your advice for an existing app that has an explicitly specified timezone and also uses .Net code such as DateTime.Now?

Comment: search and replace /g